# SQL Server Mirror issue on Mirror side

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, mirror, database-mirroring

Team,

I am having an issue on one of my Mirroring environment. It is SQL2008R2. DB mirror was somehow broken between principle and Mirror side. Someone(Not sure who is he/she due to offshore support) Manually remove mirroring from principle side. Ideally it should remove mirror from Mirror side and get the DB in recovery status.

Now It looks like mirror is not completely removed on Mirror side as DB's are still in (Mirror, Synchronous /Restoring) status.

I checked the DB on primary side and that DB status says it is not involved in mirror so looks like mirror is completely removed from principle side but somehow it is not cleared on mirror side.

Now it is not allowing me to delete DB on mirror side. As it complain that DB is involved in mirroring so can't be removed.

Any idea how can I recover DB on mirror side ?

I already try to remove mirror partner from Principle but says it is not involved in Mirror.

Can't delete DB on mirror side as well as it error out that DB is involved in Mirror.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this from another site, you may be able to try this:  (On the mirrored server) - "I have shut down SQL Server services and renamed the .mdf / .ldf files to something different and restarted the SQL Server.

I was then able to take the database offline. And then I was able to drop it. I restored the database from Primary and was subsequently able to set up mirroring."

Comment: Please post a link to where you found it. We love references. =)

Comment: Sure - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33235/cannot-remove-mirroring-nor-restore-or-delete-databaseerror-3456-sql-server